# Flutter & Firestore: How to check the commit() of the batch is a success or not?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The basic code is:

```
Future batchSet() async {
  WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
  for (var value in dataList) {
    batch.set(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('batch').doc(), {
      'createAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'data': value,
    });
  }
  await batch.commit();
}
```

How to check the result when committed?

I tried `await batch.commit().then((value) {});` but the `value` type is void, can't do anything with `value`.

Or I just use this:

```
try {
    await batch.commit();
  } catch (e) {}
```

Is this work fine if I use try/catch with only the `commit()`?

Comment: I explained the flow below. If that doesn't answer your question, please edit it to explain what type of result you expect for a successful commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise can end in two ways:

- It can either resolve, in which case its `then` clause is executed with the result of the call passed as a parameter. In the case of a `batch.commit` there is indeed no result.
- Or it can be rejected, in which case its `catch` clause is executed with an error object to indicate what went wrong.

Since you're using `async`/`await`, the `then` clause is essentially the code in the same code-block right after the `await`ed call. To catch a rejection, use a `try-catch` block as you did in your last snippet. The `e` parameter has information on why the promise/commit failed.